# Can gRPC be used to write realtime applications like multiplayer games?

Tags: go, server, grpc, game-development, multiplayer

Lately, I've been reading about Google's gRPC. And I am wondering if it's a good choice for a real-time application like a multiplayer game.

For instance, can we build a game server with gRPC for a real-time multiplayer game?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, however, real-time multiplayer games usually prefer UDP over TCP for streaming because TCP can have a lot of latency due to features like reordering and packet acknowledgement.

gRPC run uses HTTP/2 which used TCP, which would make it unsuited in some cases.

This however doesn't stop you from using [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) which is the message serialization used by gRPC, if that is a feature you like.

Comment: Hmm, So maybe it will be ideal for a turn-based game but not for a real-time game

Comment: @BerkeKaanCetinkaya Pretty much anything works for turn-based games. The only real consideration is "does latency matter to your game". gRPC isn't a solution to achieving extremely low latency, you're comparing two different axis.

Comment: In games where every millisecond counts it is not recommend, but you can for example still use it for non-latency sensitive data transfer like game maps, scores, chat.

Comment: What about QUIC/Http3 which uses UDP for connections?

Comment: QUIC could work if you use unreliable datagrams [RFC9221](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9221.html) but default QUIC implements similar mechanisms as TCP for reliability which make it less suited for low latency streaming